# Managing conflicting dependencies in Java

Tags: java, ant, dependency-management

I have a scenario where our application uses Hibernate 3.5.2 (I know it is old but it is battle tested and we can't change it) and I also recently had to add PowerMock for some tests. The issue here is that the Hibernate version is so old that it uses Javassist 3.9.0.GA whereas the oldest version of PowerMock (which I can't use anyway but regardless) starts from Javassist 3.12.0.GA. Also the old versions of javassist have some issues which are only solved with later ones such as 3.20.0.GA.

How can I manage the in order for our tests to run properly? I've read about loading classes with different class loaders and although it is complicated I'm willing to try (we have a bunch of reference code in our codebase regarding custom class loaders). Is there another way? We're using Ant as a build script so no Maven/Gradle shenanigans are available.

EDIT: I just found out that PowerMock throws an exception if it is loaded from any classloader except the system class loader. Is it still possible to override the SCL (using -Djava.system.classloader property)?